# Closest number with conditions applied

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find the closest number to a number I input from a list of number depending on certain conditions.  Currently I'm

```
=SMALL($C$3:$C$16,COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$16,"<"&$E3)+1)
=LARGE($C$3:$C$16,COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$16,">"&$E3)+1)
```

$E3 is the number I input. C3:c16 is the range of numbers I'm looking to.  I take the ABS value of both results and which ever is closest to E3 I take.  This works fine.  However I want to introduce a condition.  If any cell in Range $B3:$B16 contains "Apple" (as example) I want to exclude the number in column C from my calculation.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Ciaran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you need to use an [Array-Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7). The following formulas should work like your functions with the desired criteria added:

```
{=SMALL(IF($B$3:$B$16<>"Apple",$C$3:$C$16),COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$16,"<"&$E3,$B$3:$B$16,"<>Apple"))}
{=LARGE(IF($B$3:$B$16<>"Apple",$C$3:$C$16),COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$16,">"&$E3,$B$3:$B$16,"<>Apple"))}
```

*Note*: You need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter the formula as an array formula.

Comment: Fabian - Thank you very much for your support.